# What's the difference between "Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition" and "Minecraft"?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, version-differences, minecraft-bedrock-edition

On the Nintendo Switch eshop, there are two versions of Minecraft: "[*Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition*](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/minecraft-nintendo-switch-edition-digital-version)" and "[*Minecraft*](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/minecraft-switch)". The *Switch Edition* is currently unavailable for purchase, with a message that says *Minecraft* is available as a free upgrade for existing owners.

The store page lists that the new version has new features such as crossplay, but it seems to be missing a few features from the *Switch Edition*, such as the ability to transfer worlds from the Wii U Edition.

What are the differences between *Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition* and *Minecraft* on the Switch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition* is the older version of the game that does not offer crossplay with other platforms. In other words, you can only play with other Nintendo Switch players in this version of the game.

*Minecraft* is the more recent version of the game that runs off of the Bedrock engine. It allows crossplay with the Xbox One, Windows 10, and Pocket editions of the game, which also run off of the Bedrock engine. Marketplace assets carry over between all of these versions also, including MINECOINS. A Microsoft account is required to unlock this feature.

*Minecraft* can be installed via a patch for those that already own *Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition*. In addition, you can transfer your DLC purchases from *Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition* over to *Minecraft*.

[[source]](https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/better-together-nintendo-switch)

Comment: Sounds like exactly what happened with the *Minecraft Xbox One Edition* and *Minecraft*.

Comment: [The FAQ](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/2944851) notes that *Minecraft* does not currently support world transfers from Wii U, which *Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition* allowed.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Despite that, *and this is a guess on my part*, you can likely transfer Wii U worlds to *Minecraft: Nintendo Switch Edition* before installing the patch, and have it transfer after the patch is installed.

Comment: It isn’t treated as a patch. The two games are treated as separate downloads.

Comment: Thought otherwise. Regardless, transferring a save from Wii U to *Nintendo Switch Edition* and then to *Minecraft* would theoretically work.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft Nintendo Switch edition does not have updates such as the new 1.12.0 update. It also does not offer different resource packs or cross-platform multiplayer. The only resource pack it offers is "Mario Mash-Up". It also does not offer Eshop copies, which means it is gamecard only.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft: Switch Edition was the original console port of the game before the Switch got a port of Bedrock (which is what the current Minecraft is on that platform). Once the Bedrock port came out, all updates on Switch Edition stopped.

So the differences are:

- Cross play with all Bedrock ports of the game (XOne, Win10, PS4, Android, iOS)
- Gets the current Minecraft at the same time as other platforms. This alone makes the list of changes rather extensive.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Minecraft Nintendo Edition" can only be played with other Nintendo users, and cannot go with Xbox player, PlayStation players, etc.
The "Minecraft" can be played with other gamers.